# I can assign value to pointer after freeing it from manually allocated memory

Tags: c, malloc

I am not sure why I am getting value 3490 evven if the author says *p = 3490 should be ERROR since we are doing it after free(). Any ideas?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    // Allocate space for a single int (sizeof(int) bytes-worth):

    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *p = 12; // Store something there

    printf("%d\n", *p); // Print it: 12

    free(p); // All done with that memory

    *p = 3490;          // ERROR: undefined behavior! Use after free()!
    printf("%d\n", *p); // Print it: 3490
}
```

I tried compiling and value still shows up. I do not see any undefined behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior can mean "appears to work properly"

Comment: It just means you are using memory not owned by that pointer.

Comment: @dbush probably the most dangerous possibility.

Comment: While I'm certain this is merely pedagogical, do _not_ `malloc` a single `int`.

Comment: As long as the pointer points to a valid address (within the address space of the process) no error will be raised (e.g. `segfault`). A call to `free` tells the memory manager that the memory block at `p` can be reused again. Using invalid(-ated) pointers can definitively lead to memory corruption but as long as it is happening in the space the process has access to, the underlying system does and will not care (at least not mandatory). So UB yes, ERROR no.

Comment: _I am not sure why I am getting value 3490..._ neither is anyone else. That depends on what your OS did with the memory after you `free`d it, which would be most difficult to reliably discern. Certainly not worth your time to try to figure it out.

Comment: Who is that author? Can you quote (not paraphrase) them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) Particularly: _"So mostly this burden falls upon the human C programmer, who must know what they are doing and what they shouldn't be doing. The system is not "required" to produce segmentation faults, access violations etc."_

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI it was from beej's c book. the comment is all I have "ERROR: undefined behavior! Use after free()!", no explanations related to it

Comment: @yano aren't you curious?

Comment: @gulpr yeah kind of. However, saying 'anything can happen' (as i think is implied in the answer) doesn't mean or explain why something happens.

Comment: @stark what do you mean by that? Does that mean memory address of p that had 12 in it is no longer there? so 3490 is not in the location where 12 once was? Would appreciate your elaboration

Comment: You should have read earlier in the book "don’t do anything that causes undefined behavior, ever" and then "It’s undefined behavior to use a memory region after you free() it".

Comment: [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/775806) (it discusses a slightly different error, but pretty much everything there applies to this one too).

Comment: not really .. there's so many variables that go into that it would be practically impossible to understand. .. whatever your OS happens to be doing at the time, different compiler flags can affect things. You would essentially need to understand every minute detail of how your OS handles memory, probably what the C runtime is doing, and those details are going to change with version to version of compiler, system, architecture. But if that's how you want to spend your time, the source is out there (for linux). Good luck

Comment: you'd be far better served putting effort into learning solid programming practices, and learning to identify and avoid undefined behavior. Eric Lippert's answer linked above my comment is an excellent metaphor for UB.

Comment: my 2 cents best guess, I think most memory managers don't necessarily reclaim memory right when you `free` it. You `malloc` it, the OS allocates some memory to your process (probably more than you asked for), and even when you `free` it isn't necessarily returned to the system right away. Memory is very abundant and cheap these days. Does your multi-gig system really care about reclaiming 4 bytes right now? Probably not. Once the process exits the OS will reclaim all the memory (including your `malloc`) allocated to the process. But I have not studied memory management in detail.

Answer (score 7):

> if the author says *p = 3490 should be ERROR

The author does not say that. The text says “ERROR”, not “should be ERROR”.

The author is not saying the compiler should report an error. The author is not saying the program should report an error. The author is not saying the operating system should report an error.

The author is saying the person who wrote the code made an error.

Then it says “undefined behavior”. That means the behavior of the program is not defined.

There is no definition, no specification, in the C standard for what the program is required to do. There is no specification that it will report an error. There is no specification that it will not report an error. There is no specification that it will print “3490”. There is no specification that it will not print “3490”.

The lesson is you must learn not to make such errors, and the C programming language will not help you find them.

Comment: so what is this error?

Comment: @Mathology: `printf("%d\n", *p);` attempts to use the memory that `p` pointed to, `*p`, after the reservation on that memory was released with `free`. It is an error to write code that attempts that, the same way it is wrong to attempt to get back into a hotel room without permission after you have checked out.

Answer (score 2):

> `*p = 3490` should be ERROR ...

No.
"`*p = 3490` should be ERROR" is *defined behavior*.
`*p = 3490` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as the value in `p` is invalid after being free'd.  Anything may happen.
There is no *should*.

C does not require emitted code that checks for such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

- After using free() on a pointer, the memory it points to is marked as free, but the pointer itself doesn't change.
- It still points to the same location, which may now contain different data, as it can be overwritten.
- To avoid using a freed pointer, set it to NULL after freeing it.

Comment: Re “the pointer itself doesn't change”: When the lifetime of an object ends, the value of a pointer to it becomes indeterminate, per C 2018 6.2.4 2.